# Is it safe to charge Lithium Ion battery directly with a 4.2 volt supply?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, lm317, tp4056

I have been working with Lithium ion 3.7 volts batteries and have been charging them using TP4056 module. However, the module doesn't last longer and gets damaged within a couple of weeks or a month. I thought about supplying a 4.2 volts regulated voltage to the battery instead of using TP4056 module to charge it. I used LM317 IC with two external resistors which gave me 4.18 volts, 0.8A output. Is it safe to directly charge the cells using this circuit? No issue if the battery is not fully charged to 4.2 volts but I want to know will it protect the battery from overcharging, damage and something dangerous like a fire?

Comment: The datasheet shows that some LM317 ICs can produce 3.4A. What limits your current to only 0.8A?

Comment: Clueless about that, but I measured it with multimeter and the output was 0.8A while the input was 1.5A.

Comment: https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-409-charging-lithium-ion has useful info.

Comment: You did not say the size (max charging current) of your Li-Ion battery cell.

Comment: Battery size is 2000 mAh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a good idea - Li-Ion batteries really need a proper CC/CV charger. Switching for a fixed voltage supply is not a suitable approach.

The charging circuit shouldn't be dying after a month, unless the ICs are defective/counterfeit or wired up wrong. I would suggest identifying the cause of the fault, or using a different charger though one still designed for Li-Ion batteries. There are many different Li-Ion charging ICs out there to choose from.

Comment: TP4056 is widely used . So many fake version are in market . I suggest use another ic charger like me . more expensive and better . Without charger ic you face with battery explosion and fire and bad things ...